# Can i add "gedit" or "sublime" editor in the Tkinter window?

Tags: tkinter, sublimetext3, gedit, tkinter-text

I am currently using a text widget used in tkinter and wanted to replace it with a sublime editor or gedit editor. Is it possible?

Thank you,
Dhruv Gupta

Comment: sublime and gedit are standalone softwares and though there are some (mostly old, in tcl) hacks to embed some external windows in Tk, you won't really be able to interact with them like with a text widget (e.g. get the text content, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. It's not possible.